# What is a method to notify you when things "don't" happen?

Tags: php, linux

I have lots of different scripts and quite a few cron jobs that trigger different things throughout the day.  Many times it is to download data from an external API or to periodically run a script of some type.

However, I am at a loss in finding a simple method to notify me if these things don't happen.  For example, recently, something happened on one of my servers that caused all the cron jobs to stop running.  It took a few days before I started getting complaints that things weren't working right.  What are some of the methods you use to make sure things happen on a regular basis?

Answer (score 2):

Nagios supports a type of check called "Passive Checks". Normally Nagios directly monitors a thing such as whether a server pings or a service is up using Active Checks. i.e. you ping a server, or ask about the status of a service every five minutes. If there's no response or the underlying nagios check script reports a failure then Nagios will eventually mark that host or service as "Hard Down". Then depending on your notification and alert rules you'll be alerted that something is broken.

Some checks such as checking if cronjobs have run is a bit more tricky because you can't directly ask a cron job if it ran. I guess you could write a script to trawl your cron logs to see if a cronjob ran within a certain time period but it can get complicated.

However, Nagios can be configured to "Passively" check for an "UP" status that is submitted to Nagios in a certain period of time by external services. So instead of Nagios directly polling for a status, you can turn things around and have your scripts submit a success/fail status to Nagios.

So say you have a task that should run every 24 hours. When the task completes it would submit a result directly to Nagios. On Nagios you'd configure a passive check to make sure this result appears within a window of 24 hours. If it doesn't (for example `crond` crashed or something deleted the cron job entry) then Nagios would alert you that it's had no result.

Relevant Nagios documentation:

> http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/passivechecks.html

This article shows a worked example:

> http://www.admin-magazine.com/Archive/2014/22/Nagios-Passive-Checks

The key to all this is the passive service check `freshness_threshold`, i.e. if Nagios doesn't see a new result within that timeperiod then it'll raise an alert.

Answer (score 0):

These situations are typically what server monitoring tools such as [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/) and [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) are used for. These tools will allow you to monitor your server's up-time, alerting you (and also allowing you to take action) in case of anomalies.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: "server uptime" itself is largely irrelevant :}

Comment: I respectfully disagree :O). He mentioned, " something happened on one of my servers that caused all the cron jobs to stop," I felt like one of these situations could have been the server could have completely been down (has occurred to me more than once on AWS ;)!

Comment: If the server 'died' a cron job would be least of my worries .. *shrug*.

Comment: I definitely agree with you there, I just wanted to cover the things that came to my mind :0); I also agree with the context and perspective you're speaking with, thank you!

Comment: Ya, the whole server is obviously monitored.  But a mis-configuration just caused linux to stop running cron jobs (It might have been a permissions issue or something where the cron could no longer run the scripts.)  Nevertheless, normal server monitoring would not be useful here.

Comment: @user1452536, not true; there are actually some great plugins into Nagios; such as "Cronjob Exit Codes With Nagios" and Icinga (https://www.icinga.org/) which would cover your situation quite well ;) Please let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up an account at https://www.setcronjob.com/ - then your crons run independently of your server, you can manage crons on multiple servers, get more fine grained control of timings, and so on.